Fantasy manga where the main character is getting accidentally killed by dragons
Like the title suggests, I'm looking for a manga where the main character (MC) is accidentally killed and reincarnated or revived by different dragons and this happened to him more than once. I do apologize as I do not remember all the details but here is what I can recall:
The MC of the manga is seriously unlucky as he was accidentally killed by a dragon. In order to make it up to the MC, the dragon reincarnates him and gave him the type of magic it controlled. This is followed by the MC yet again being killed by a dragon and the same thing happens. This happens repeatedly to the MC until he has many types of magic he can control. Pretty sure he could control chaos and other elements.
The story is then passed to the dragons; it turns out all the dragons that killed the MC were meeting up for something. They then talked about something important, I believe, and how they accidentally killed a human, so they reincarnated him and gave him control of some elements.
IIRC, at least one dragon takes human form and goes to the MC, as it was like the first time ever a human had the power of every dragon.
Details relating to when I read it:

I believe the last time I read it was a year ago. I was introduced to it by a manga recap channel, but there is a good chance the channel and or the video has been taken down.
I do not remember if it was coloured. My guess would be that it was black and white.


Is this My reincarnated craftsman life after being run over by a dragon three times...?
From the official site (auto-translated from Japanese):

The life of an adventurer who is over 40 years old and does not get better. At that time, I was run over by a dragon and died. Even in the life where I was reincarnated as an apology, I was run over again and died. After all, I was run over in my third life (ry So I decided to live my fourth reincarnation life as a craftsman instead of an adventurer. After all, the alimony that the dragon gave him to apologize for running over him is provided at the cheat level, and some beautiful busty older sisters will take care of it...... It's all smooth sailing.



Ah yes, busty older sisters. That doesn't seem at all creepy or weird.
